# ¿Cómo dicen cuando quieren reservar el uso de un objeto para ustedes exclusivamente?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Estoy traduciendo un texto del inglés al español que tiene la frase *I call the swing*. El contexto tiene a unos niños llegando a un parque con juegos y un niño quiere el columpio/hamaca para él primero, o para él exclusivamente.

En México, yo diría *Aparto el columpio*. Pero también he leído *Me pido el columpio*, aunque no sé en qué región lo dirían así.

Busqué la [definición](https://dle.rae.es/apartar) de *apartar* en la RAE, y no veo que alguna de las acepciones incluya este uso, por lo que me imagino que el uso de *apartar* es muy local.

¿Cómo lo dirían ustedes y en qué región lo dicen así?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En ese contexto que comenta, en que varios niños van hacia un parque infantil para jugar con los distintos instrumentos de juego que allí se encuentran y donde teóricamente cada uno elegiría en un principio el que más le gusta, en España, al menos en mi zona diríamos;

Por ejemplo;

- "Yo me pido el columpio". (*Yo me pido jugar/montarme en el columpio*)
- "Yo me quedo con el columpio".
- "Yo me pido el tobogán el prime" (primero). (Yo me pido tirarme el primero en el tobogán)
- "Yo me pido subir el primero por las cuerdas".
- (El otro chaval que lo escucha) "Yo me pido subir el segundo por las cuerdas".
- Otro que lo escucha, por ejemplo, yo voy detrás de Rafa.

Comment: Si,  pedirse para call, tambien conocido como: I have dibs on x.

Answer (score 1):

En España sí se dice "Me pido el columpio" o "me pido el columpio para mí". También puedes decir "el columpio para mí". Los niños pequeños, además, suelen decir directamente "el columpio es mío", ya que a veces tienen problemas para entender el concepto de propiedad.

Answer (score 1):

En Argentina, usamos la palabra "hamaca" para "swing". Nunca usaríamos el verbo "pedir". Un niño diría:

- ¡Yo **quiero** la hamaca!

Si no se trata de niños, se puede oír:

- Déjenme la hamaca / Dejen la hamaca para mí.